# Bash Script String Comparison Operators

Tags: linux, bash

I guess this is a two part question. I'm trying to write if statements with values that are ripped from a website and are strings. However I would like them to be integers so I can use integer comparisons with them. But the info I could find online basically yielded no results as far as converting the values to integer. I'm left with this code that yields errors if I use ">=" and no errors when just using "=". So is there a way to convert strings to int? And if not, how can I write this to execute without errors and why am I receiving errors with the current construction?

```
 #!/bin/bash

    webpage=$(curl http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KPNE.xml | grep 'visibility_mi>')
    webpage2=$(curl http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KPNE.xml | grep '<weather>')

    #Test code:
    #echo $webpage
    #echo $webpage2

        extrct=${webpage%</*}
        extrct=${extrct##*>}

        extrct2=${webpage2%</*}
        extrct2=${extrct2##*>}

        echo -en '\n'
        echo ===============================================
        echo Output Variables Values testing purposes:
        echo $extrct   
        echo $extrct2 
        echo ===============================================  
        echo -en '\n'          

            if [[ $extrct2 == 'Rain' ]]
            then 
                echo 'Rain!'
            elif [[ $extrct2 == 'Snow' ]]
            then
                echo 'Snow!'

                elif [ $extrct >= '7' ]
                then
                    echo 'All Clear!'
                elif [ $extrct >= '4' and < '7' ]
                then
                    echo 'Limited Visibility'
                elif [ $extrct < '4' ]
                then
                    echo 'Very Low Visibility!'
            fi


    read
```

Comment: `>=` is not the shell `[` arithmetic operator. `-ge` is. Similarly `-gt`, `-lt` and `-le`. See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions

Comment: Better use arithmetic expansion in bash. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion.

Comment: In bash, the most robust *"conversion"* is to use the arithmetic `$((string))` to return a numeric value. The `$(())` arithmetic construct provides the most robust handling of this type of semi-conversion and will return 0 if it cannot convert what is in the given string.

Comment: `echo -en '\n'` is a verbose and nonstandard way of writing `echo`.

Comment: So I could convert the string and declare it to a new variable by writing something like.... newVar=$((oldStringVar)). At that point I would be able to use arithmetic operators like -ge, -lt, etc with the newVar variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bash, to compare variables as integers you have to use different comparsion operators. Here are a few:

- -gt = greater than
- -ge = greater than or equal to
- -eq equal to

See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html for more operators.Note that all variables are still stored as strings.

EDIT: Here is a fixed if-statement:

```
            elif [ $((extrct)) -ge 7 ]
            then
                echo 'All Clear!'
            elif [ $((extrct)) -ge 4 -a $((extrct)) -lt 7 ]
            then
                echo 'Limited Visibility'
            elif [ $((extrct)) -lt 4 ]
            then
                echo 'Very Low Visibility!'
        fi
```

Comment: When using those operators I receive the error, "[: 4.00: integer expression expected". I've tried those operators, and this is where I've hit the wall in figuring this out. I know it's basic, but when learning the simplest of things can trip you up.